# Display a scrollable image from a url in android studio

Tags: android, url, scroll, imageview, android-ion

I'm trying to create an activity that display an image that is obtained from an url. I want the width of the image to adapt the screen but the height of the image can be longer than the screen so that the image becomes scrollable (vertically). 
First of all, I displayed the image from a drawable folder and it worked with the following code :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">



        <ImageView

            android:src="@drawable/programme"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I obtained what I wanted :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/imPkZ.png

But now I wanted the image to charge from an URL so I used the ion library :

```
Ion.with(imageView)

            .load("http://...");
```

The image load but it is no longer scrollable and doesn't display as wanted.
http://i.gyazo.com/704324724364235bbe417d5447265c42.png

Do you have any solution?
Thanks

Comment: In which direction are you want to scroll ?

Comment: I would like to scroll in the vertical direction.

Comment: one way is to create custom imageView and make vertical scrolling enable and another on is to put imageview into vertical scrollView

Comment: Isn't it what I've done by putting imageView inside ScrollView?

Comment: what problem are facing if you putted into scrollView

Comment: When the image is in the drawable folder it is working well but when I use ion to get the image from a URL the result is that: http://i.gyazo.com/704324724364235bbe417d5447265c42.png not scrollable and not displayed as wanted

Comment: Try using:


    .smartSize(false)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seems to change anything @koush

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by setting android:layout_width="match_parent" in ScrollView, ImageView and LinearLayout and setting android:adjustViewBounds="true" for ImageView like this :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```